# Passing an argument to a node causes 404

Tags: uri

On my page I have a block that reads a variable in the URL.  The page that it reads it on is a node.  When I pass an argument through the URL to the node, it causes a 404 error. ex:

```
www.example.com/experience //This is the node, it works
www.example.com/experience/asia //Asia is the argument, I get 404
```

I've tried configuring the URL Alias to "experience/*", but this obviously didn't work and only accepts '*' as the argument.  What do I need to configure to make this work?

I've heard of some modules that automatically add the aliases to the configuration table, but I would prefer a more straight-forward solution.

Comment: What kind of page is this?  A node-view page, something declared via hook_menu, a panel page, a view page, etc?

Comment: It's not a hybrid page or anything, just simply a content node which has the alias 'experience'.  You could also view this with 'node/4', etc.

Comment: I think describing what the block is going to do with the argument will help others to brainstorm solutions... because passing an argument to a node is not really a normal Drupal function, more likely than not there is probably a module which can help you here depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four points to consider:

- When you set a path alias, the asterisk is not used as wildcard character; this means that when you set experience/* as path alias, you are really saying to Drupal that http://example.com/experience/* is the path alias, not that http://example.com/experience/ followed by any string is the path alias.
- If http://example.com/experience is the path alias for http://example.com/node/4, http://example.com/experience/asia is not an alias for http://example.com/node/4/asia.
- Even if you would have set http://example.com/experience/asia as alias of http://example.com/node/4/asia, visiting http://example.com/experience/asia you would get a "page not found" error, as there are no modules that handles a path like http://example.com/node/4/asia
- Using the path in that way to pass arguments to a block shown in a node page is wrong, especially when the argument can be any string. What would happen if you access http://example.com/node/4/edit? Should "edit" be understood as part of the path, and Drupal should show the node edit form, or should be taken as argument to the block, and Drupal should simply show the node?

It is better if such parameter is passed as query string, for example in a URL like http://example.com/node/4?continent=asia. If you really like better to use a URL like http://example.com/experience/asia, then with Drupal 7 you can implement the following hooks.

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if ($path == 'node/4') {
    $path = 'experience';

    if (!empty($options['query']['continent'])) {
      $path .= "/{$options['query']['continent']}";
      unset($options['query']['continent']);
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
  if (preg_match('|^experience(/(.*))?|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'node/4';
    $_GET['continent'] = $matches[2];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are modules to accept subpath aliases.

If you're on Drupal 6 then look into the [subpath_alias](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) module.

Drupal 7 has [subpathauto](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) which does the same thing.

What they do is expand Drupal's path matching to work with subpaths, so no extra aliases are added. I've used it in the past when embedding views within nodes and it worked a treat.

So if you have `node/4` aliased to `path/test` then it will recognise `path/test/argument` as `node/4/argument`

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your url from

```
www.example.com/experience/asia
```

to

```
www.example.com/experience?type=asia
```

you should be able to access `asia` and any other "type" from your block like this:

```
$types = drupal_get_query_parameters();
foreach ($types as $key => $value){
  switch ($key) {
     case 'asia':
       // code for asia goes here...
       break;
     case 'europe':
       // code for europe goes here...
       break;
     // etc
  }
}
```

Otherwise, as the comments suggest, `www.example.com/experience/whatever` is going to fail because drupal hasn't declared a menu item for that path.  However, variables can be passed in practically anywhere without drupal needing to know about them all as they don't change the base url.

If you still wanted the "cleaner" looking url, I suppose you could create a hook_menu() item like:

```
 $item['experience/%'] = array(
   'title' => 'Experience',
   'page callback' => 'experience_type',
   'access callback' => TRUE, 
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
```

and then function called `experience_type` that returned the contents of `node/4` or whatever `experience` is aliased to. Then, in your block you could do something like:

```
switch (arg(1)) {
   case 'asia':
     // code for asia goes here...
     break;
   case 'europe':
     // code for europe goes here...
     break;
   // etc
}
```

and if all is good in the world, `www.example.com/experience/asia` would work.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to implement `hook_menu()` and make a custom callback by placing a placeholder after your URL.