# Passing arguments to a node with an alias url

Tags: path-aliases

There is a similar issue in here:
[Passing an argument to a node causes 404](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32731/passing-an-argument-to-a-node-causes-404)

But there is no real viable solution.
I tried using the sub-pathauto module but the restiction of 8 arguments is too little, since the urls will look something like this:

`www.site.com/alias/key/value-1/key/value-2/key/value-3/key/value-4`

and it can go on for a while.
It works when instead of `alias` i have `node/nid`.

Is it possible to have it work with any amount of dynamic arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e not tested with more than 8 args, but I enabled path_alias_xt when passing args to a node Alias with /mynode/term-name/tid and the 404s magically went away.

https://www.drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt

Further more using
print_r(arg(2));
in the node template prints "term-name"