# How do I add custom keywords in the URL?

Tags: uri

For a sake of SEO, I need to be able to dynamically pass random keywords to the URL. For example, instead of the classic *variable=value* couples in a query (e.g. /my-node-title?selected=random-seo-keyword), I need to use a good-looking path like /my-node-title/random-seo-keyword, where *my-node-title* is a URL / path alias of node/xxx but *random-seo-keyword* does not exist in the structure and may not be predefined.

Then, on the server I handle and split the URL parts with a script. The only problem is that currently Drupal 7 returns a 404 error in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your paths by using `hook_url_*_alter()` hooks.
Have a look at `hook_url_inbound_alter()` and `hook_url_outbound_alter()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this module https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto thanks to [Paul Jones](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25/paul-jones) answer in this post [Passing an argument to a node causes 404](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32731/passing-an-argument-to-a-node-causes-404?rq=1)

This module correctly recognizes Drupal paths in links and avoids 404 errors.